# Fetch API request to my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, react-native

I'm trying to call an API to show information on my website in React.js, the API needs a token to be read, but I don't know what I have to do to generate the token, since my application doesn't need any register or login. It's like a catalog of products and you can personalize them. I don't understand very well this because I'm new and I'm learning all by myself, so I'm sorry if this is confusing, feel free to ask anything, I'll try to answer :)

Here's the code I have until now:

```
export class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      models: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(myUrlAPI)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          models: json
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded, models } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>{models.map(model => <li>{model.name}</li>)};</ul>

          <a href="/sofa">
            <div className="Parcelas">
              <img
                src="../../img/image-card-1@2x.png"
                className="ParcImage"
                alt="sofa"
              />
              <h1>Sofa hipnos</h1>
              <h2>
                1,200<span>€</span>
              </h2>
              <p className="Features">
                w 20.5 x 15.5 x h 19.5 (cm)<br />Pele
              </p>

              <button className="Botao">
                <p className="MostraDepois">See Details</p>
                <span>+</span>
              </button>
              <img
                src="../../img/points.svg"
                className="Decoration"
                alt="points"
              />
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

In the `<ul>` tag I was just trying to test the results from the **json**.

Also, everytime I use `.map` to make an array, I get this error (`TypeError: models.map is not a function`) or similar, can you tell me why?

Comment: `models` is an array in your state initially, so I would guess that the `json` you set as `models` when the fetch is completed is most likely not an array. Could you do `console.log(json);` before `setState` and see what the data looks like? It will be hard to help you with `needs a token to be read`, since you haven't told us what API you are using.

Comment: The console.log(json) returned this: `{detail: "Authentication credentials were not provided."}` @Tholle

Comment: Alright. Setting your array to that will not work. You must likely want to do some additional logic in your first `then` callback, e.g. `then(res => { if (!response.ok) { throw Error(response.statusText); } else { return res.json(); } })` and add a `catch` at the end of your promise chain, e.g. `.catch(error => console.error(error))`

Comment: Returns the same message and nothing else...

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: Django REST framework

Comment: How about you ask your colleagues how to get a token? There is not enough information in your question for us to help you.

Comment: There should be some kind of token that need to be send in headers in your api call. Ask the creator of api for it. 
And accordingly send in api call.

Comment: I have the token, but how do I send it? @Krina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way and for token you need to confirm with the backend developer as how and what you should send.

```
 let token = '1234567'; 
    fetch(myUrlAPI, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "authorization-key": token
      }
    }).then(res => res.json()
    ).then(function(json) {
      this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          models: json
        });
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
```